# Выполнить функцию из другой ячейки в UIcollectionView?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3, xcode7

есть коллекция в ней две ячейки кастомизированы по разному.
В одной cell есть кнопка по нажатию которой должен меняться текст label другой ячейки.
Почему то когда я нажимаю на кнопку ничего не меняется?

```
class cell1:UICollectionViewCell{
//button
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleChangeDate), for: .touchUpInside)
func handleChangeDate(){
  cell2.changeLabel()
}

}

class cell2:UICollectionViewCell{
//label

func changeLabel(){
self.label.text = "123"
}

}
```

Comment: Когда кнопка добавлена в первую ячейку то она изменяет текст лейбл в первой ячейке но не изменяет во втрой и наоборот

Comment: `Class BaseCell : UICollectionViewCell{
        //button
        //label1
        //label2
        //foo() {download data}
        //foo2() {change label1 and Label2 text}
        //button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(foo2), for: .touchUpInside)
}
class Cell1 : BaseCell {
        addSubView(label1)
        addSubView(button)
}
class Cell2 : BaseCell {
        addSubView(label1)
}`

Comment: Код добавьте в вопрос, а не в комментарий. А для того чтоб что-то появилось нужно сделать reload. Или таблицы, или нужной ячейки.

Comment: @VAndrJ а почему тогда текст в первой ячейки меняется без релоад. Или когда я кнопку добавлю вместо первой ячейки во вторую, то лейбл второй ячейки меняется, но не меняется текст у лейбла первой ячейки.